# Component renders for a few seconds before redirecting - React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It is normal behaviour that the current component is been rendered before it will be redirected to other route?
[image: evidence]

I have my list of routes wrapped in `Switch`:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={About} />
      <LoginRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Then custom route components `LoginRoute` which redirects to `/login` when user is not authenticated and `PrivateRoute` which renders the component when authenticated otherwise redirects to `/login`

LoginRoute:

```
const LoginRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }: LoginProps) => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={props =>
        auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: {
                from: props.location
              }
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

PrivateRoute:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  exact,
  path,
  location,
  component: Component,
  ...props
}: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      exact={exact || false}
      path={path}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: {
                from: location
              }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Then the `Router` is wrapped in AuthProvider.

AuthProvider:

```
const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<RouteProps> = ({ children }) => {
  //states
  useEffect(() => {
    GetCurrentUser();
  }, [state.isAuthenticated]);

  const GetCurrentUser = async () => {
    await API.get("/user/current")
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          authenticatedUser: response.data,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          isRetrieving: false
        });
      })
      .catch(_error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          authenticatedUser: null,
          isAuthenticated: false
        });
      });
  };

  const SignIn = async (user: UserCredential) => {
    await API.post("/user/authenticate", {
      ...user
    })
      .then(response => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          authenticatedUser: response.data,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          isRetrieving: false
        });
        localStorage.setItem(USER_TOKEN, response.data.token);
      })
      .catch(_error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          authenticatedUser: null,
          isAuthenticated: false
        });
      });
  };

  const SignOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN");
  };

  return (
    <AuthProvider
      value={{
        ...state,
        signIn: SignIn,
        signOut: SignOut,
        getCurrentUser: GetCurrentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Its taking me ages to solve this issue. Hopefully someone can help.
Currently using react router v5.1.2

Comment: Pretty sure this is normal behavior. On page refresh, the auth status will be undefined (false) until the API response returns. That's why it goes to the login page initially.

Comment: You can add a custom component while isAuthenticated state is false and render that instead while fetching data.